# Registry key not found after Java10 installation on Win10

Tags: java, registry, windows-10-desktop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2JcP.jpg)

The key is required and the registry does not contain it after the newest Java install. Could anyone advise how to edit the registry to update this path?

Uninstalling and reinstalling Java 10 brought no expected result in registry.

Comment: Why do you need that registry key? Which installer, provider, architecture, JRE/JDK and version are you using? If it is Java 10, then why are you using an old and end of life version of Java (in September 2018) instead of a current one? Java 10 was one of not Long Term Support releases, it was supported for a few months only.

Comment: Which Java installer are you using? For example the Eclipse Adoptium Temurin installer will only create registry keys if you explicitly enable it in the installer (though I'm not sure if it creates _this_ registry key).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll search for the newest version at first. The key is demanded by an old application I am using, which utilises Java and this application is yelling for the reg key.